# Regex for repeatable pattern with exclude characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Tried different variations but couldn't found one that would be aplicable for my requirements. I need regex for the following case:

`someString.someString.someString`

This pattern (`'someString.'`) can repeat any amount of time but the dot should not be at the end. More over, spaces and any symbols are not allowed at the end too. The following are invalid:

`someString.someString.someString ?`
`someString.someString.someString eq`

I tried smth like `^([a-zA-Z]+)(\.)([a-zA-Z]+).*[^\s?]$` but it doesn't process redundant characters in the end properly. If anyone has idea regarding correct regex please leave the comment

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `^([a-zA-Z]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]+)*$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like work? -> `^[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)*$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+)+$
```